# Creative way to clone quantum data?

Tags: entanglement

My goal is to think of a creative way to clone quantum data, specifically, forensically examine a quantum hard drive or memory of the future.

No, I don't think I can violate the No Cloning Theorem or bypass the Measurement issue. But I was wondering if a creative addition, such as using quantum teleportation or something like that could be used?

For example, what if with every qubit of data (X) on a quantum hard drive, we also required a separate, "assigned" Bell pair (A=B). So every time we create X we also entangle it with A (A=X=B). Could B, outside the hard drive be used to read X? Or am I begging the question...because it would be impossible to entangle X without changing X from it's original state or something like that? Could some mechanism like redundant probability "reads" be used...like something borrowed from quantum error correction ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So the no cloning theorem doesn't preclude you from creating the state
$$\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \rightarrow \alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle,$$
it just says you cant create
$$\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle \rightarrow (\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle)(\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle).$$

So yeah, you could do something like create a state like the first state, and then you would have "cloned" the measurement statistics in one basis. That is, if you were only interested in the Z basis measurement statistics of the qubit, and you apply a CNOT to it to create the state $\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle$, you would have two qubits which you could measure and sample from that distribution. But only one of them could be measured before the wavefunction collapses, and only the Z basis distribution would be preserved. This is because in the X basis, the state would not be of the form $\gamma|++\rangle + \delta|--\rangle$.

That's the closest I can think of.

Comment: I don't completely understand your answer...a little above my limited understanding of the notation and quantum logic gates. I'm trying to determine in what order entanglement must happen to measure X as stored in memory unchanged? Must I entangle A and X first, before X is stored, or A and X and B before X is stored?

Comment: So what you're trying to do is the thing that the no-cloning theorem prevents. You can't take a state, 'store' it while making a copy, and then measure your copy to get any information about the stored case.

Comment: But can I make an entanglement ahead of time, or a three-way entanglement, A=B=X, then do the storage or computation (so that all three have the same value) and measure B? Sort of like teleportation with the three-way entanglement made up ahead of time before X becomes some stored value?

Comment: so creating A=B=X is the step that violates the no-cloning theorem. It is impossible to create a quantum state that is "equal" to another state by copying it. You can replicate the same steps to get there (IE if your state A is the result of applying some gate to $|0\rangle$, you can get another $|0\rangle$ state and apply the gate again) but if I hand you a qubit in some state, there is no way to copy that state onto a qubit of your own and then return my qubit without its state untouched.

Comment: How is that we can communicate information using quantum teleportation then? Aren't two Bell pairs (A=B and A=X) being used to communicate X between A & B along with an classical channel? So, to be a pain, but I think you helped me to see that my confusion lies between the difference between the No Cloning Theorem and Quantum Teleportation.

Comment: In teleportation, the first state is destroyed by the measurements as the second state is created, so at no point do you have two of the same state.

I think your confusion is coming partially from notation. When you say A=B I assume two single qubit states which are equal, but this is not a bell pair. Do you mean the state $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$? This is a different state than $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$, which would be A = B.

Comment: In teleportation, X quantum state is somehow communicated to B. In quantum networking X is somehow communicated to B. But the No Cloning Theorem says I can't copy/communicate X from one place to another. How can X be communicated in teleportation and networking but not from direct copying? How is X able to be teleported to B in teleportation but not in copying? That's what I don't understand. I apologize for being obtuse.

Comment: I think it would help if you go through the teleportation circuit step by step, teleporting some state $|\psi\rangle  = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$, and see what the state of the three qubits is after each gate. What you'll find is that at no point are there two qubits in the state $|\psi\rangle$ at the same time. Essentially the coefficients are transferred through entanglement and measurements, but it isn't done in a way similar to a classical copy and paste.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can *approximately* clone quantum states. This idea was introduced in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9607018), and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511088) describes many of the quantum cloning variants. There are some circuit implementations of various quantum cloning variants, including [quantum telecloning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00125) ([see also](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10164)), [state depending cloning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.11424), and [various universal quantum cloning experimental demonstrations](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-021-00375-5).

Comment: Thanks for the response.